# convert MS Access sql statement to MS SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

What would be the conversion of this MS Access sql statement to MS SQL statement:

```
Select * 
from iapt 
where appt_id in (Select distinct appt_id 
                  from iaptd where po_id in(Select distinct po_id 
                                            from irct 
                                            where verify_dtim = Date()-1))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: `DATE()` isn't a valid SQL Server function, but `GETDATE()` is.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only need to change

```
Date() - 1
```

to

```
DATEADD(dd, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: `DATE` and `GETDATE()` aren't equivalent. One returns a date, the other a date and time. it's unlikely that `DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())` alone will provide the correct result.

Comment: @Larnu you`re right, to be precise we can use CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), changed that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract one day from `GETDATE()` (today).

```
Select * 
from iapt 
where appt_id in (Select distinct appt_id 
from iaptd where po_id in(Select distinct po_id 
from irct 
where verify_dtim = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())))
```